# Dial localhost:5000 getsocketopt connection refused

Tags: ngrok

I am using a python barebone hello world app that runs on local just fine. I tried to use ngrok and I can't get it to load correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

OS: OSX

[image: error]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Looks like its trying to connect through ipv6, is your webapp listening on your local ipv6 address?

Comment: No. It was set on ipv4. When I set it to ipv6, it just times out.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your local host is not able to make connection through the port , 
make sure that you have opened the port 5000 through your firewall , 
you may confirm that by turning off the firewall on your OSX .

i have tried it on my own PC and i got the same error of yours , 
the reason is actually again is the firewall , but not  the one with your MAC/Windows , its the one of your internet router , i solved this issue by making port forward from my router to my pc that run the NGrock server , that means your ngrock server can run without having to rent public IP to www and you do not need dedicated online server or hosting services.

to do that follow this steps ,

find your router gate way , 
open terminal on windows and type : ipconfig / all
check the ip which listed on Default Gateway

on MAC :

On your desktop, click the Apple icon in the top left-hand corner and select System Preferences from the drop-down menu.

Select Network.

Select your Connected internet connection from the left-hand column. This may be the Ethernet section if you're connected via Ethernet cable, or the Wi-Fi section if you're connected via WiFi.

Wi-Fi: Click Advanced in the bottom right-hand corner of the window, and then select the TCP/IP tab. You'll find the default gateway address listed next to Router.

let assume your default gateway is 192.168.1.1

login to your router by pasting the default gateway ip on the browser , it should then ask for username & password  , type your username and password , 
depending on your router model , find where is  the Port Forward Option listed on your router , you may refer to online documentation of your router to find that .
if you find it , 
within the port forward page option , add new port forward row , it should ask you for wan port  , type the wan port as ( the port used to run Ngrock Server )

and local port to your computer that have ngrock server working on it , write the local port as 80

select tcp protocols as TCP / UDB

and select  the computer which host the ngrock  ( your computer name / the ip address of your computername ) //the one listed under Web Interface on ngrock terminal

all this above configuration should be filled during adding the portforward row to your internet router .

that's it , we are done ,reboot your modem .
Now you can view your ngrock link from anywhere as long as you have internet .

here is my ngrock from my pc @ home u can view it live ,

also check above comments for firewall and disable anti virus so it don't block connection

view my ngrock from my home by [clicking here](https://ce628e07.ngrok.io/inspect/http)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but it is able to make a connection through the port. I tested it on different routers to be sure, including my own mobile network, and it didn't change anything. This issue is something else, I think, but I will still try your instructions. Note: I will update you on the results soon on if it works.

Comment: i edited my post bro , i have just download it and faced same issue and above , this is how i resolved it ... u can check my ngrock i posted the link , its coming from the pc where i am commenting to u . i promise it will work , i will help you to get this done . just do the steps up if you have any issue  , type it in comment and i will help you . let me start with asking what is your internet router model ?

Comment: when you make the port forward steps ... make sure you reboot your modem router , it will not take effects until you reboot it . this is important

Comment: also , don't use 4G  / mobile connection ton the computer that run ngrock server , usually with mobile connections all ports are blocked and you cannot configure internet as it works directly from your telecom network .